# creating build on remote server: itch.io API error (400): /wharf/builds: invalid game

Tags: unity-game-engine, deployment, github-actions, game-development, continuous-deployment

I've created github actions to automate CI/CD, for a Unity project and deploy it on itch.io.
But when the deploy action runs, it gives me the error :creating build on remote server: itch.io API error (400): /wharf/builds: invalid game.
Any idea what should I do?
Here's the yml code of my github action.[And here's the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U3CqI.png)

```
name: GameCI Template 

on: push

env:
  UNITY_LICENSE: ${{ secrets.UNITY_LICENSE }}

jobs:         
 buildWebGL:
   name: Build for WebGL ️
   runs-on: ubuntu-latest
   strategy:
     fail-fast: false
   steps:
     - name: Checkout code
       uses: actions/checkout@v3

     - name: Create LFS file list
       run: git lfs ls-files -l | cut -d' ' -f1 | sort > .lfs-assets-id

     - name: Restore LFS cache
       uses: actions/cache@v3
       id: lfs-cache
       with:
         path: .git/lfs
         key: ${{ runner.os }}-lfs-${{ hashFiles('.lfs-assets-id') }}

     - name: Git LFS Pull
       run: |
         git lfs pull
         git add .
         git reset --hard
     - name: Restore Library cache
       uses: actions/cache@v3
       with:
         path: Library
         key: Library-build-WebGL
         restore-keys: |
           Library-build-
           Library-
     - uses: webbertakken/unity-builder@v2
       with:
         targetPlatform: WebGL

     - uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
       with:
         name: build-WebGL
         path: build/WebGL
         
 deployPages:
   needs: buildWebGL
   name: Deploy to Itch.io 
   runs-on: ubuntu-latest
   steps:
     - name: Checkout code
       uses: actions/checkout@v3

     - uses: actions/download-artifact@v2
       with:
         name: build-WebGL
         path: build

     - name: Display structure of root files
       run: ls -R
       working-directory: build/WebGL

     - name: Deploy 
       uses: JamesIves/github-pages-deploy-action@4.1.4
       with:
         TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
         branch: itch-io
         folder: build/WebGL
         
     - uses: manleydev/butler-publish-itchio-action@master
       env:
         BUTLER_CREDENTIALS: ${{ secrets.ITCH_IO_API_KEY }}
         CHANNEL: HTML
         ITCH_GAME: unityci
         ITCH_USER: abdurrehmanmuhammad
         BRANCH: itch-io
         PACKAGE: build/WebGL
```

I want the CI/CD actions to work in order to deploy the game at itch.io sucessfully.